# Rails 5 Attempting to generate a URL from non-sanitized request parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Rails 5 in my application, and for the link_to find below my code and using will_paginate,

```
  <%=link_to text, params.merge({controller: controller, action: action, page: 1,
    order_field: field, order_dir: dir}) %>
```

The above code is throwing below error

> Attempting to generate a URL from non-sanitized request parameters! An
>   attacker can inject malicious data into the generated URL, such as
>   changing the host.

Even I tried using permit as below and avoided the above error,

```
<%=link_to text, params.permit!(page: 1).merge({controller: controller, action: action, 
    order_field: field, order_dir: dir}) %>
```

But, this in-turn is raising an issue through my rspec as below,

> Failure/Error: render
>        ActionView::Template::Error:
>          undefined method `permit!' for {:show_aliases=>"true"}:Hash
>        # ./app/views/shared/_sort_column.html.erb:10:in`_app_views_shared__sort_column_html_erb___3232147907220672307_98274920'

Any help for a workaround for this.

Comment: Try generating this hash `params.permit!(page: 1).merge({controller: controller, action: action, 
    order_field: field, order_dir: dir})` inside your controller and then using it in view.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not doing this in your controller?  It seems like a violation of the MVC pattern, since the view should not be caring about parameter strength, the controller should be.  If you can keep these kinds of concerns within the controller your app code will be more straightforward to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `params.permit` (without the exclamation point):

```
<%=link_to text, params.permit(page: 1).merge({controller: controller, action: action, 
order_field: field, order_dir: dir}) %>
```